# Multivalued dependencies and BCNF/4NF

Tags: database, database-normalization

What happens with multivalued dependencies? Would they fall under BCNF or fourth normal form or such?

Answer (score 1):

4NF involves eliminating multi-valued dependencies.

Lower normal forms, including BCNF, involve functional dependencies.

Wikipedia's articles on the normal forms are actually pretty good.

- [4NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form)
- [BCNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form)